# Excel date & time formula-round up cell value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time

I'm preparing a report of usage statistics for a group study room reservation system we use at the library where I work. I've exported all the reservations from MySQL in Excel for the past year and am trying to come up with an average figure for all the scheduled reservations.

The formula I'm using to calculate the differences between the start time and end time of each reservation, `(=TEXT[end_time]-[start_time],"h:mm")`, works great but I have a problem. The ending times for the reservations are listed as 00:29 when one ends on the half-hour, and 00:59 when it ends on the hour.

I've got a couple thousand lines in my spreadsheet and don't want to resort to using Find & Replace to change these values to 00:30 and 00:00. Is there a way to amend my formula so that it will round up the ending time, or possibly add one minute to the ending time in the formula.

Comment: I really hope you mean your formula is `=TEXT([end_time]-[start_time],"h:mm)` because having the open-parenthesis before the equals generally doesn't work.

Comment: Also, it's a little odd that your formulas are returning 29 & 59 minutes. Sample testing on my own suggests it should be an even 30 & 60 if the meetings are starting and ending on hours and half-hours. Perhaps the data from your database is including seconds? We could work around that instead.

Answer (score 1):

Edit based on Iszi's comment:

```
end_time - start_time + TIME(0,1,0)
```

[Documentation for the TIME() function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/time-function-HP010342955.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP010342402)

**Original answer:**

You can add 1 minute in your end_time - start_time calculation by realizing that in Excel 1 day is equal to the integer 1, so your formula would be something like:

```
end_time - start_time + 1/24/60
```

(Dividing by 24 hours and 60 minutes).

Comment: Without having to do the calculation yourself, you could do `+TIME(0,1,0)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it without math. For start time in A1 and end time in B2:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(B1-A1,"h:mm"),":29",":30"),":59",":00")
```

SUBSTITUTE is a fairly simple text substitution function. It requires three parameters:

1. Original text
2. String to be replaced.
3. Replacement string.

SUBSTITUTE *only* replaces text when there is a match to parameter 2, and then it *only* replaces the matching text - the rest of the string is left alone, and strings that don't have a match at all are left untouched.

So, we start out above with the original time calculation from your question. That gets passed to a SUBSTITUTE that checks for ":29" and replaces with ":30". (If ":29" isn't found, it does nothing.) then the resulting string gets passed to the outermost SUBSTITUTE which checks for ":59" and replaces with ":00" as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If your start and end times are exactly on the hours and half-hours, your formulas should not be returning durations of 29 or 59 minutes. I expect it's possible the database export also includes some seconds on the times. We can eliminate seconds entirely, and calculate durations that assume start/end are at zero seconds into each minute, like this:

(Start is in A1. End is in B1)

```
=TEXT(TIME(HOUR(B1),MINUTE(B1),0)-TIME(HOUR(A1),MINUTE(A1),0),"h:mm")
```

TIME is a function that will generate an excel "serial number" using given hours, minutes, and seconds, and then display it in a standard time format. "Serial numbers" are how Excel stores date/time values on the back-end. When you see something like `8/1/2014 15:26:57` in a cell that's been configured for date/time formatting, Excel is actually storing the value as `41852.64372` - this represents the number of days (with the decimal portion being a fraction of one day) since roughly `1/1/1900 0:00:00` (it's slightly more complicated than that, but this is already more than you need to know).

HOUR and MINUTE are functions (yes, there's a SECOND - and a DAY, MONTH, and YEAR if you need them) which return their respective portions from a date/time serial number.

So, what we're doing above is taking the times from A1 & B1, zeroing out the seconds from each of them, and *then* doing the subtraction.

Comment: I assumed that they were saying the start times are all on the hour or half hour (e.g. 0 or 30), and the end times are a minute earlier (e.g. 29 and 59), probably because of how the scheduling software works (no overlapping start/stops).

Comment: Can't tell for sure from the details here, so anything's possible. There's about thirty different ways to skin this cat regardless.